# Is there a simple instance $(m,n)$ to visualise $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrix space?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

It is possible to visualize an $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ space; granted $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ etc are not, but that is OK -- there is one intuitive example. Is there any instance of matrix space $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ that could be visualized?
[image]

Comment: Usually coordinate vectors are written as columns, not rows. That said, it's not usually possible to 'visualize' things without some hand-waving. Everyone falls to this temptation, it's not really fruitful though. High dimensional Euclidean space just 'looks like' lower dimensional Euclidean space. This is reasonable since the inner products are basically the same, so all the metric notions are pretty much the same too.

Comment: Matrices are often used to represent maps (functions). In your case it would be $M: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$, which means that you can map a vector $v$ from $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto a vector $w$ from $\mathbb{R^3}$ by $Mv=w$

Comment: Observe that $\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{mn}$, but we cant imagine properly a vector space with more than $3$ dimensions, so if $mn>3$ the space is not visualizable, at least with this simple isomorphism.

Comment: @B.Swan If matrices are indeed meant to be used as operators, this would make them quite different beasts from vectors, which are variable-like (and the whole question of trying to visualize a matrix space would be inappropriate, just as saying that a vector is just a $1 \, x \, n$ matrix).